# how to trim all rows in table with big rows

Tags: php, sql

Hi guys i want to trim all rows in table i have this query :

```
global $db;

        $sql = 'SELECT *
                FROM ' . PROFILE_FIELDS_PLUSMW3_TABLE . '
                WHERE ' . $db->sql_in_set('serialnumber', array_map('intval', $user_key));
            $result = $db->sql_query($sql);
```

but because of i want to do that in a big forum so its very risky then i need to know if this way is true or not i will thank full if someone help me. and my way is:

```
WHERE ' . $db->sql_in_set(trim('serialnumber'), array_map('intval', $user_key));
```

Comment: "trim all rows"? Huh? trim as in strip leading/trailing whitespace?

Comment: actually i want to select serialnumber row with trim. and trim as both l/t whitespace

Comment: `trim('serialnumber')` is pointless. `'serialnumber'` is a fixed string and has no whitespace, so trim will just return it as-is.

Comment: so you say there is no need to trim serialnumber ?!

Answer (score 0):

I get the impression you're worried about [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection), in which case you should have a look at prepared statements.

If that's not the case, please clarify your question.